# Spring Boot - GET atributes in common from repository jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I started working with spring boot's rest API and ended up having some specific problems returning the last two topics

1- GET animals/number/{number}
You should list the animals with the number/code {number}

2- GET animals/name/{name}
You should list the animals with the name {name}

3- GET animals/species/{species}
You should list the animalsof the species {species}. Note, more than one animal can be returned for each species.

4- GET animals /type/{type}
You should list the animals of the type {type}. Note, more than one animal can be returned for each type. Due to the nature of this field, you should perform a substring search. For example, the value  “poison” for the {type} should return the animals with the type "reptile/Poison".

what I got

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/animals/number/{number}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getNumber(@PathVariable(name = "number") String number) {        
   Optional<Animal> o = repository.findByNumber(number);

   if (!o.isPresent())
       return new ResponseEntity<>(o, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

   return new ResponseEntity<>(o, HttpStatus.FOUND);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/animals/name/{name}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<?> getName(@PathVariable(name = "name") String name) {
       Optional<Animal> o = repository.findByName(name);

       if (!o.isPresent())
           return new ResponseEntity<>(o, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

       return new ResponseEntity<>(o, HttpStatus.FOUND);
   }
```

I tried to do topic 3 but I'm not able to:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/animals/species/{species}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getSpecies(@PathVariable(name = "species") String species) {
      
   List<Animal> p = repository.findAll();

  if (species == null)
    repository.findAll().forEach(p::contains);
  else
    repository.findByTitleContaining(species).forEach(p::contains);

  if (p.isEmpty()) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
  }

  return new ResponseEntity<>(p, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface AnimalRepository extends JpaRepository<Animal, Integer> {

    Optional<Animal> findByNumber(String number);
    Optional<Animal> findByName(String name);
    Optional<Animal> findByspecie(String species);
}
```

i put for test //localhost:8081/animals/name/Animalname

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can query all animals matching the searched specie using a *Spring Data* generated query (as the one you seem to have defined):

```
List<Animal> findByTitleContaining(String specie);
```

Then you can group the returned elements using the `java.util.stream.Collectors#groupingBy` using the `Animal` types:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/animals/species/{species}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getSpecies(@PathVariable(name = "species") String species) {
          
    List<Animal> matchingAnimals = repository.findByTitleContaining(species);

    if (!matchingAnimals.isEmpty()) {
        final Map<String, List<Animal>> groupedAnimals = matchingAnimals.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Animal::getType));  
        return new ResponseEntity<>(groupedAnimals, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```